# How to stop IE from creating pixelated buttons?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I know I'v run across this before but for some reason IE decides to pixelate my submit button.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 7):

The pixelation usually occurs in IE6 and IE7 only as it was fixed in IE8:
[Bug 101](http://webbugtrack.blogspot.com/2007/08/bug-101-buttons-render-stretched-and.html)

The trick is to apply CSS to the button...

```
/* Apply CSS class "button" to your input buttons */
.button{
  width:auto; /* fix stretching in IE for 16-20 char buttons */
  overflow:visible; /* fix stretching in IE for 16-20 char buttons */
  padding-left:4px; /* force sensible padding in IE */
  padding-right:4px; /* force sensible padding in IE */
}
```

This doesn't **solve** everything, but it certainly minimizes the effect.

The following screen shot shows all the button (with the styles applied) have "respectable" padding (e.g. it doesn't grow wildly).  Also note that at some point the buttons still fail and pixelate... but you can squeeze a bunch more characters in before they fail. (up to 25 chars vs. 19... depends on font family and size)

[IE Button stretch partial fix http://img523.imageshack.us/img523/3990/iebuttons.png](http://img523.imageshack.us/img523/3990/iebuttons.png)

Comment: do you have a sample page we can peek at? I'm always up for a challenge!